# Trying to follow a tutorial about SQLite, but don't get the desired result. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, sqlite, visual-studio-code

At the moment, I know the basics of Python and want to go a bit further.

I'm practicing with python and SQLite and want to create a (fictional, for now) database. It's about public book closets on the streets in Amsterdam, with their locations and the books they contain. I followed a YouTube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=girsuXz0yA8), but don't get the desired result. I'm using Visual Studio Code as IDE.

**Here's the code I wrote**

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('boekenkast.db')

cursor = connection.cursor()

commmand1 = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
boekenkast(boekenkast_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, location TEXT, latitude FLOAT, longitude FLOAT)"""

cursor.execute(commmand1)

command2 = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
boeken(boeken_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, writer TEXT, title TEXT, FOREIGN KEY(boekenkast_id) REFERENCES boekenkast(boekenkast_id))"""

cursor.execute(command2)

# add book shelfs to boekenkast

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO boekenkast VALUES (0001, 'Meeuwenlaan 21', 52.38330303722245, 4.912016781394647)")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO boekenkast VALUES (0002, 'Pasteurstraat 11', 52.34968085037797, 4.935466766049933)")

# add books to boeken

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO boeken VALUES (00001, 'Gerard Reve', 'De avonden', 0001)")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO boeken VALUES (00002, 'Anya Niewierra', 'De camino', 0002)")

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM boeken")

results = cursor.fetchall()

print(results)
```

---

I tried to correctly make a database and was hoping to at least not get an error if I ran it. Hope you can help me out.

This is the error I got.

```
PS C:\Users\gebruiker\OneDrive\Bureaublad\Programmeren\Bookadaba\Bookadaba> & c:/Users/gebruiker/OneDrive/Bureaublad/Programmeren/Bookadaba/venv/Scripts/python.exe c:/Users/gebruiker/OneDrive/Bureaublad/Programmeren/Bookadaba/Bookadaba/Bookadaba/database_utils.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\gebruiker\OneDrive\Bureaublad\Programmeren\Bookadaba\Bookadaba\Bookadaba\database_utils.py", line 15, in <module>
    cursor.execute(command2)
```

Comment: You missed the most important line of the traceback: `sqlite3.OperationalError: unknown column "boekenkast_id" in foreign key definition`.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. Sorry, I still don't get it. The boekenkast_id is a parameter of boekenkast, and I added it as a foreign key parameter to boeken. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You defined "FOREIGN KEY(boekenkast_id)", but there is no column "boekenkast_id" in this table.

Comment: You should edit your question to include the full traceback, including the actual error message

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You didn't define the column `boekenkast_id` in the table `boeken`. Defining a column and defining a foreign key are two seperate things.

Here is the changed code:

```
command2 = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
    boeken(boeken_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    writer TEXT, 
    title TEXT, 
    boekenkast_id INTEGER, 
    FOREIGN KEY(boekenkast_id) REFERENCES boekenkast(boekenkast_id))"""
```